# navigation.getparam latest value is not accessible inside didFocus listener

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, use-effect

I am having 2 screens in a react native app, both the screens are functional components.
A button on screen 1 leads to screen 2, I select a few checkboxes on screen 2 and click on a button to navigate to screen 1  with adding navigation params.

coming back on screen 1 runs didFocus listener, but param values are undefined, when I hit ctrl+s on in code editor, useEffect runs and values become accessible.

After this, going back to screen 1 from screen 2 runs didfocus listener (as expected) but the param values do not update.

below is useEffect code in screen 1.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        navigation.getParam('from') == 'TagFiltersScreen' ? getAllQuestions('mostInsightful', navigation.getParam('tagsFilter')) : getAllQuestions();

        const listener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {

            navigation.getParam('from') == 'TagFiltersScreen' ? getAllQuestions('mostInsightful', navigation.getParam('tagsFilter')) : getAllQuestions();

        });
        return () => {
            listener.remove();
        }

    }, []);
```

Comment: Seems similar to this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4653

Comment: I guess so, But I am using navigation.getParam('tagsFilter') only

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and here is how I am doing it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isFocused = props.navigation.isFocused();
    if (isFocused) {
        const { params } = props.navigation.state;
        navigationFocus(params);
    }
    const navigationFocusListener = props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', (payload) => {
        const params = payload.state.params;
        navigationFocus(params);
    });
    return () => {
        navigationFocusListener.remove();
    };
}, []);
const navigationFocus = (params) => {
    if (params) {
        
    }
}
```

I'll be curios to know if there is a better way of doing this.